# AccessDeniedException while trying to copy a file into the startup folder of windows

Tags: java, access-denied

The title of this question explains it all. I tried to copy my jar into the startup folder, when I start it the first time. After that I want to create a start.bat to start the jar every startup of windows.

My question is, how can I bypass this security measure and give this jar the necessary rights?

```
try {
    Files.move(Paths.get(f.getPath()), Paths.get(Constants.startupDirectory.getPath()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(Constants.startupDirectory, "start.bat", Constants.startCode);
} catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error appears at line 3. What can I do?

Comment: Seems that you're having issues with privileges. I would suggest to check on how you're running your java program.

Comment: What kinds of starting a jar are good to avoid this limitation.

Comment: There are at least two startup folders in Windows, a system one and a user one. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use the user folder